# Generar un pdf con ñ y acentos desde base de datos TCPDF

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, tcpdf

Estoy intentando generar un **PDF**  con **tcpdf** donde se visualizara la lista de una tabla, el **pdf** se genera pero sale en blanco cuando esa lista contiene al menos una **"ñ"**,he tenido problemas con los caracteres que ya solucione al insertar y modificar, pero ahora que debo modificar en el **PDF**?

Código, con este código edito el **pdf** pero no pude colocarlo completo, el resto es una tabla.

```
include('../vista/data_pdf18.php'); 

  ob_start();
  ob_clean();


  require_once('../vista/assets/tcpdf/tcpdf.php'); 

  $obj_pdf = new TCPDF('l', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);  
  $obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);  
  $obj_pdf->SetTitle("Export HTML Table data to PDF using TCPDF in PHP");  
  $obj_pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);  
  $obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));  
  $obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  
  $obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');  
  $obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);  
  $obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '10', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);  
  $obj_pdf->setPrintHeader(false);  
  $obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);  
  $obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);  
  $obj_pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);  
  $obj_pdf->AddPage('l');  


  $content = '';  
  $content .= '
```

código de la conexión a base de datos:

```
<?php  
function fetch_data()  
{  
  $output = '';  
  $conect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mirenacer");
  $sql= "SELECT * FROM paciente";
  $result = mysqli_query($conect, $sql);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  {       
    $output .= '
    <tr> 
    <td width="8%">'.$row['paci_doc'].'</td>  
    <td width="8%">'.$row['paci_nom'].'</td>
    <td width="8%">'.$row['paci_ape'].'</td>
    <td width="8%">'.$row['paci_cel'].'</td>
    <td width="8%">'.$row['paci_tel'].'</td>
    <td width="8%">'.$row['paci_dir'].'</td>
    <td width="5%">'.$row['paci_eps'].'</td>  
    <td width="5%">'.$row['paci_esc'].'</td>
    <td width="5%">'.$row['paci_ocu'].'</td>
    <td width="8%">'.$row['paci_fecha_ing'].'</td>
    <td width="8%">'.$row['paci_fecha_nac'].'</td>
    <td width="5%">'.$row['paci_aco'].'</td>
    <td width="5%">'.$row['paci_rel'].'</td>
    <td width="5%">'.$row['paci_foto'].'</td>
    <td width="5%">'.$row['paci_pro'].'</td>

  </tr>  
  ';  
}  

return $output;  
}  

 ?>
```

Comment: El error no esta en esa parte del código

Comment: Voy añedir el phph  que se llama desde ahi, el cual contiene la consulta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Investigando y probando con la librería encontré la raíz del problema y la solución:

El problema es que la base de datos al contener caracteres especiales (como 'ñ' o caracteres con acentos) produce un error en la conversión a html.

Para resolverlo basta agregar la siguiente linea de código:

```
$conect->set_charset("utf8");
```

De modo que este segmento queda:

```
$conect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mirenacer");
$conect->set_charset("utf8");
$sql= "SELECT * FROM paciente";
$result = mysqli_query($conect, $sql);
```

Lo probé y funciona, espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: hasta ahora pude volver a conectarme,dame unos minutos y reviso y te doy tu like ,gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias ha funcionado perfectamente :)

Comment: @Yero, de nada, me da gusto que te haya servido.